# MySQL Workbench 6.2.5 quit unexpectedly on MAC OS X 10.8.5

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL Workbench 6.2.5 on MAC OS X 10.8.5. However, when I want to open this application, it is not opening and just mentions "MySQLWorkbench quit unexpectedly."

Any idea on how to fix this?

**Update:**

I installed the 6.1.7 version and its working fine. It would be still great if someone could answer this question regarding the updated versions. Even the bug reports available on `bugs.mysql.com` did not solve this problem.

Comment: The current version of MySQL workbench is 6.3.3. You should upgrade.

Comment: Even with the new version installed, I still have this problem.

Comment: Please have a look at wb.log and report a bug. Execute something like "cat ~/Library/Application\ Support/MySQL/Workbench/log/wb.log" to view the log contents.

Comment: Did you check the log ?

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the following folder

~/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench

once the application is relaunched the folder will be recreated.

Comment: Before removing that folder I recommend to take a look at wb.log in the logs folder to see if there's anything that gives a hint as to what is causing the crash.

Comment: this will remove all the saved connection. Be warned!